# Script to change ownership of folders in Plesk vhosts

Tags: batch-file, permissions, ownership

I'm looking for some help in creating a shell script in Linux to perform a batch ownership change for certain folders in a Plesk environment where the owner:group is apache:apache.

I want to change the owner:group to :psacln.

The FTP user can be ascertained by looking at the owner of the httpdocs folder.
^this is the section I'm having trouble with.

If I was to set all owners to be the same, I could do a one-line:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs -user apache -group apache -exec chown user:psacln {} \;
```

Can anyone help plug the user in to this command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... for those who may want to use it in the future:

```
    for dir in /var/www/vhosts/*
    do
        dir=${dir%*/}
        permissions=`stat -c '%U' ${dir##*/}/httpdocs`
        find ${dir##*/}/httpdocs -user apache -group apache -exec chown $permissions {} \;
    done
```

Comment: Superb. I had to tweak slightly for slightly different scenario, but this saved my bacon on several servers with loads of site on each many of which had migrated over from other servers with slightly random permissions!

Answer (score 0):

Since `stat` doesn't work on al unices in the same way, I thought I would share my script to set the ownership of all websites to the correct owners in Plesk (tested on Plesk 11, 11.5, 12 and 12.5):

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/
for f in *; do
    if [[ -d "$f" && ! -L "$f" ]]; then

        # Get necessary variables
        FOLDERROOT="/var/www/vhosts/"
        FOLDERPATH="/var/www/vhosts/$f/"
        FTPUSER="$(ls -ld /var/www/vhosts/$f/ | awk '{print $3}')"

        # Set correct rights for current website, if website has hosting!
        cd $FOLDERPATH
        if [ -d "$FOLDERPATH/httpdocs" ]; then
            chown -R $FTPUSER:psacln httpdocs
            chmod -R g+w httpdocs
            find httpdocs -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;

            # Print success message
            echo "Done... $FTPUSER is now correct owner of $FOLDERPATH."
        fi

        # Make sure we are back at the root, so we can continue looping
        cd $FOLDERROOT
    fi
done
```

\\\

**Explanation of code:**

1. Go to vhosts folder
2. Loop through websites
3. Store vhosts path, because we are using `cd`in a loop
4. If `httpdocs`folders exists for the current website, than
5. set the correct rights of httpdocs and
6. all underlying folders
7. Show succes message
8. `cd` back to vhosts folder, so we can continue looping

\\\